# Calling contract method results in metamask error using ganache

Tags: web3js, ganache-cli

I have a simple Vue form, that calls a method in an Ethereum contract.
If I don't provide a callback to my method, Metamask complains:

> Uncaught Error: The MetaMask Web3 object does not support synchronous methods like eth_sendTransaction without a callback parameter.

So I added this. (even though I already have a callback in my sendTransaction)

Then I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendTransaction' of undefined

In my console.log I can clearly see the method on dash.crowdsaleContractInstance, and the sendTransaction property as well.

I'm using Ganache CLI v6.7.0 (ganache-core: 2.8.0)
and metamask web3 api version: 0.20.7

Im calling my method on the instance of the contract not the contract object

I tried this as well as found in the documentation: 
`myContract.methods.myMethod(123).send...`
but the methods property is not available, so I guess I'm on another version of web3?

I've done a fair share of web3 smart contract programming by now, but I still find it very hard to debug, to be honest. Anybody who can help to find what is going wrong here?

`dash` is an object where I instantiate a lot of async functionality

Thanks.

```
vmBuyform = new Vue({
el: '#buyForm',
data: {
  to: dash.crowdsaleaddress,
  from: accounts[0],
  amount: 0.25
},
methods: {
  buy: function (event) {

    var sender = this.from;
    var receiver = this.to;
    var amountVal = this.amount;

    var amount = web3.toWei(amountVal, 'ether');
    console.log(dash.crowdsaleContractInstance);
    console.log(abis.crowdsaleContractInstance);
    console.log('Version: ', web3.version);

    // does not work with metamask enabled, works without metamask
    dash.crowdsaleContractInstance.depositFunds({from:sender, to:receiver, value: amount, gas: 2000000},
      function(error, result){}).sendTransaction({from:sender, to:receiver, value: amount, gas: 2000000},function(error, result){

      if(!error){
          console.log(result);

      }
      else{
          console.error(error);
      }

    });
  }
}
})
```

Comment: "so I guess I'm on another version of web3?" - Correct, if the `methods` property is not available, then you're using web3.js v0.x. The official documentation for this version is [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3js-api-reference). I recommend switching to v1.2.1 or higher, but not higher than the highest v1.x.

Comment: How web3 is create? How dash.crowdsaleContractInstance is created?

Comment: Solved, the problem was something else... in the contract coins were send, but the sender address had an empty balance.